# For loop in Pyomo Constraints

Tags: pyomo

I am struggling on making multiple constraints using for loop in Python Pyomo.
My code concept is the following

```
T = 504
model.times = RangeSet(0, T-1)
model.Machines = Set(initialize = Machines_parameters.keys())
```

Then I've divided model.times in 3 sets of the same length and now I want to write specific constraints for each of this part of the set. The following is an equivalent but simplified version of the code:

```
for k in range(3): #number of parts in which I've divided the set [(0,167),(168,335),(336,503)]
    for j in range(cluster_index[k][0], cluster_index[k][1]):   #respectively first and last number of the subset
        def logic_constr(model,i):
            if j >= const1[k] and j < const2[k]:
                return model.z[i, j + 1] - model.z[i, j] == model.dsu[i, j + 1] - model.dsd[i, j + 1]
            else j==const2[k]:
                return model.z[i,const2[k]] - model.z[i,j] == model.dsu[i,const1[k]] - model.dsd[i,const1[k]]
        model.logic_constr = Constraint(model.Machines, rule = logic_constr)
```

What I would like to do is to iterativelly create 504 different constraints, each one with its own rule. 
Do you have any suggestion on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have formulated the constraint right now, you will only end up with having one constraint at the end, since after every loop, the constraint will be overwritten.

Since, as you say and according to your for loops, you also want one constraint per time step, this is much simpler.

First, you need to define the constraint as:

```
model.logic_constr = Constraint(model.Machines, model.times, rule = logic_constr)
```

This means that the constraint will be applied for each member of the set `model.times` i.e. there will be 504 constraints for each element of the set model.Machines.

Then all your ifs and the for loops can go into your definition of the `logic_constr` function.

Comment: So you're saying that to avoid overwriting the constraint I must first define the constraint as following: model.logic_constr = Constraint(model.Machines, model.times, rule = logic_constr) and then define the function: def logic_constraint with all the for loops and if statements, right? In this way I'm applying 504 different constraints for each machine

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Generally, if a constraint in your model applies for all (or a subset of) elements in a set, then you need to add it in your constraint definition. Then in the constraint rule, you can have the function return a different equality/inequality depending on the actual value of the set element. If for some elements the constraint does not apply at all, then you can have the function `return Constraint.Skip`. If my answer was helpful, you can accept it :)

Comment: The problem is that if I define model.logic_constr = Constraint(model.Machines, model.times, rule = logic_constr) before writing the function logic_constr, it doesn't work because the constraint calls the function before it is written

Comment: Yes that’s expected. You should define the constraint after the function :)